# Subgroups of $ \mathbb{Z}_n$ (integers mod $n$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Is $\langle 15 \rangle$ a subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z}_{18}$  (the integers mod $18$)?

There is a theorem in my book that says for every divisor $k$ of $n$, $\langle n/k \rangle$ is a subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z}_n$  . So that means $\langle 15 \rangle$ can't be subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z}_{18}$?

Comment: 1) Please use LaTeX.  2) Your question is not formulated precisely, and can't be answered until you clarify.

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 4):

The subgroup generated by $15$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$, which is what your notation means, is as the name says a subgroup.

It is also a proper subgroup as the GCD of $15$ and $18$ is not $1$. 
Indeed, $15$ and $3$ generate the same subgroup.

The result you mention gives a complete list of examples of subgroups, but this does not mean that other elements do not generate the (same) subgroups too.

Comment: Following up on what @quid said, $m$ and $n$ will generate the same subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ if and only if $\gcd(m,18)=\gcd(n,18)$, which you may verify by listing all the cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. You may restrict each of $m$, $n$ to be in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ of course.